# Changing State of Parent in React Does not Trigger re-render of children?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, reactjs, arcgis

I have an ARC GIS react component which extends a base "parent" component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react"
import "./AOPMap.css"
import { Map } from 'react-arcgis';
import BoundaryLayers from '../BoundaryLayers/BoundaryLayers'
import AOPComponent from '../AOPComponent/AOPComponent'

class AOPMap extends AOPComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleMapLoad = this.handleMapLoad.bind(this)
  }

  render() {
      alert ('Reached render');
      return (
        <Map onLoad={this.handleMapLoad} >
          <BoundaryLayers boundaryType={this.state.boundaryType} map={this.state.map} />
        </Map>
      );
  }

  handleMapLoad(map, view) {
      this.setState({ map, view });
  }

}

export default AOPMap;
```

Also extending this base parent component, is this Form:

```
import React, { Component } from "react"
import "./AOPForm.css"
import { Map } from 'react-arcgis';
import BoundaryLayers from '../BoundaryLayers/BoundaryLayers'
import AOPComponent from '../AOPComponent/AOPComponent'

class AOPForm extends AOPComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
      }

      handleChange(event) {
        console.log("Event Value: " + event.target.value);
        this.setState({boundaryType: event.target.value});
        alert('Boundary Type submitted as: ' + this.state.boundaryType);
      }

      handleSubmit(event) {
        // NOTE: Now - it will typically report back as what you changed it to - doesn't seem to pick it up on Change right away?
        alert('Boundary Type submitted as: ' + this.state.boundaryType);
        event.preventDefault();
      }

      render() {
          alert ('Reached render');
        return (
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <label>
              Pick a Boundary Type:
              <select value={this.state.boundaryType} onChange={this.handleChange}>
                <option value="point">Point</option>
                <option value="tile">Tile</option>
                <option value="flightline">Flightline</option>
              </select>
            </label>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
          </form>
        );
      }
}

export default AOPForm;
```

So, upon changing the dropdown right now I can see via some basic alerts that the state doesn't change right away, and I recall reading somewhere that React doesn't guarantee it will be something you can see right away either. However, the real problem is that when I change the state, I see that it re-renders the form (due to the alert "Reached render") - but it doesn't appear to refresh the Map who also uses that *this.state.boundaryType*.

The state being modified is defined in the parent component, defined in the constructor for this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react"
import "./AOPComponent.css"
import { Map } from 'react-arcgis';
import BoundaryLayers from '../BoundaryLayers/BoundaryLayers'

class AOPComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        map: {basemap: 'satellite'},
        view: null,
        loadedKmlLayers: [],
        boundaryType: 'point'
    };

    this.handleComponentLoad = this.handleMapLoad.bind(this)
  }

  handleMapLoad(map, view) {
      this.setState({ map, view });
  }

}

export default AOPComponent;
```

So my thought is if it re-renders whenever state is changed, why is it that when we change the state of the parent, only the Form re-renders and not the Map as well? What would be the correct way to trigger a re-render of the Map when the user is ready to submit the Form (there will be multiple fields - more than just this one - so re-rendering the Map on Change may be a bit much - ideally only want to trigger a re-render of the Map on Submit hence why I have that there as a placeholder).

Lastly, though the code probably isn't important, we render these with a "Layout.js" that simply returns divs, etc.. containing things like  then the Map, etc..

Comment: did you mean to do this? `this.handleComponentLoad = this.handleMapLoad.bind(this)` in `AOPComponent`

Comment: i would also recommend reading this https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html, inheritance should be avoided when using react components

Comment: I'll have a look, haven't seen the link you just posted yet so that's a good place to check